# Unable to pass dropdownselected data to action method in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, model-view-controller

This is my jquery code.

```
 url: 'GroupMaster/SaveNew',
                    data: {
                        grp_name: $("#grp_name").val(),
                        grp_description: $("#grp_description").val(),
                        grp_isactive: $("#grp_isactive").val()

                    },
<tr><td>Group Name : </td><td>@Html.TextBox("grp_name")</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Group Description : </td><td>@Html.TextBox("grp_description")</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Group IsActive : </td><td>@Html.TextBox("grp_isactive")</td></tr>
  Above code works fine. But now i changed last textbox to dropdown like below.
 <tr><td>Group IsActive :</td><td>@Html.DropDownList("grp_isactive", new List<SelectListItem>

                 {
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="True", Value = "True" },
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="False", Value = "False" }
                 })

</td></tr>
   Now my jquery code is not sending data to action method.
```

This is the code to get selected index of dropdown

```
 $("#grp_isactive").change(function () {

        });
        var Selected = $("select option:selected").text();
```

May be here I am going wrong

```
grp_isactive: $("#grp_isactive").val()
```

Comment: please arrange your question properly.

Comment: you have given `grp_isactive` to a `textbox` and `selectbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have given `grp_isactive` to a `textbox` and `selectbox`.

Make `id` `unique`.